# I have revoked my active development certificate ,and unable to create a new one, what is the solution?

Tags: iphone

I have revoked my active development certificate ,and unable to create a new one, what is the solution ?

edit:

I followed these instructions

Generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) with a public key
In your Applications folder, open the Utilities folder and launch Keychain Access.
Choose Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority.
In the Certificate Information window, enter or select the following information:
In the User Email Address field, enter your email address
In the Common Name field, enter your name
In the Request is group, select the Saved to disk option
Click Continue
The Certificate Assistant saves a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) file to your Desktop.
The public/private key pair will be generated when you create the Certificate Signing Request (CSR) if you use the Key Chain Assistant to create the CSR.
Submit the CSR through the Provisioning Portal to the Admin for approval.
Click the Development tab
Upload the certificate by choosing the file
Click Submit
You will be notified by email when your CSR has been approved or rejected.

Comment: Why are you unable to create a new one?

Comment: i am getting this error    " We are unable to upload this Certificate file because it is invalid. Please check the file and try again. "

Comment: I followed these instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the certificate you had created from the key chain access and repeat the steps from scratch. This may help.

Comment: i repeated the steps but when i submit the CSR, i am getting the error

Comment: Thanks, i used firefox instead of chrome